# How to access individual channels with core audio from an external audio interface

Tags: c, macos, audio, core-audio

I am learning CoreAudio and I am just going through some of the examples on Apple's documentation and figuring out how to set things up and what not. So far I am able to connect to the default connected audio input device and output it to the default output device. I connected a 2 channel interface and was able to output the input from it and output it as well.

However I was searching through their API references and examples, but could not find any thing substantial to access the individual input channels from my interface.

I was able to hack away and extract the samples from the AudioBufferList in my Render Callback function and manipulate it that way but I am wondering if there is a correct way or a more official way of accessing the data from each individual input channels.

EDIT:

This is the user data that I found from an example that I am using:

```
typedef struct MyAUGraphPlayer
{
    AudioStreamBasicDescription streamFormat;

    AUGraph graph;
    AudioUnit inputUnit;
    AudioUnit outputUnit;

    AudioBufferList * inputBuffer;
    CARingBuffer * ringBuffer;

    Float64 firstInputSampleTime;
    Float64 firstOutputSampleTime;
    Float64 inToOutSampleTimeOffset;

} MyAUGraphPlayer;
```

This is how i set up the input unit:

```
void CreateInputUnit(MyAUGraphPlayer * player)
{
    //Generates a description that matches audio HAL
    AudioComponentDescription inputcd = {0};
    inputcd.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
    inputcd.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_HALOutput;
    inputcd.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;

    UInt32 deviceCount = AudioComponentCount ( &inputcd );

    printf("Found %d devices\n", deviceCount);

    AudioComponent comp = AudioComponentFindNext(NULL, &inputcd);

    if(comp == NULL) {
        printf("Can't get output unit\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    OSStatus status;
    status = AudioComponentInstanceNew(comp, &player->inputUnit);
    assert(status == noErr);

    //Explicitly enable Input and disable output
    UInt32 disableFlag = 0;
    UInt32 enableFlag = 1;
    AudioUnitScope outputBus = 0;
    AudioUnitScope inputBus = 1;

    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(player->inputUnit,
                                kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO,
                                kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                                inputBus,
                                &enableFlag,
                                sizeof(enableFlag))
    assert(status == noErr);

    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(player->inputUnit,
                                kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO,
                                kAudioUnitScope_Output,
                                outputBus,
                                &disableFlag,
                                sizeof(enableFlag));
    assert(status == noErr);

    printf("Finished enabling input and disabling output on an inputUnit\n");

    //Get the default Audio input Device
    AudioDeviceID defaultDevice = kAudioObjectUnknown;
    UInt32 propertySize = sizeof(defaultDevice);
    AudioObjectPropertyAddress defaultDeviceProperty;
    defaultDeviceProperty.mSelector =  kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultInputDevice;
    defaultDeviceProperty.mScope = kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal;
    defaultDeviceProperty.mElement = kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster;

    status = AudioObjectGetPropertyData(kAudioObjectSystemObject,
                                      &defaultDeviceProperty,
                                      0,
                                      NULL,
                                      &propertySize,
                                      &defaultDevice);
    assert(status == noErr);


//Set the current device property of the AUHAL
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(player->inputUnit,
                                kAudioOutputUnitProperty_CurrentDevice,
                                kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                                outputBus,
                                &defaultDevice,
                                sizeof(defaultDevice));
    assert(status == noErr);

    //Get the AudioStreamBasicDescription from Input AUHAL
    propertySize = sizeof(AudioStreamBasicDescription);
    status = AudioUnitGetProperty(player->inputUnit,
                                kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat,
                                kAudioUnitScope_Output,
                                inputBus,
                                &player->streamFormat,
                                &propertySize);
    assert(status == noErr);


    //Adopt hardware input sample rate
    AudioStreamBasicDescription deviceFormat;
    status = AudioUnitGetProperty(player->inputUnit,
                                kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat,
                                kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                                inputBus,
                                &deviceFormat,
                                &propertySize);
    assert(status == noErr);

    player->streamFormat.mSampleRate = deviceFormat.mSampleRate;

    printf("Sample Rate %f...\n", deviceFormat.mSampleRate);

    propertySize = sizeof(AudioStreamBasicDescription);
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(player->inputUnit,
                                kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat,
                                kAudioUnitScope_Output,
                                inputBus,
                                &player->streamFormat,
                                propertySize);
    assert(status == noErr);

    //Calculating Capture buffer size for an I/O unit
    UInt32 bufferSizeFrames = 0;
    propertySize = sizeof(UInt32);
    status = AudioUnitGetProperty(player->inputUnit,
                                kAudioDevicePropertyBufferFrameSize,
                                kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                                0,
                                &bufferSizeFrames,
                                &propertySize);
    assert(status == noErr);

    UInt32 bufferSizeBytes = bufferSizeFrames * sizeof(Float32);

    //Create AudioBufferList to receive capture data
    UInt32 propSize = offsetof(AudioBufferList, mBuffers[0]) +
                    (sizeof(AudioBuffer) * player->streamFormat.mChannelsPerFrame);

    //Malloc buffer lists
    player->inputBuffer = (AudioBufferList *) malloc(propSize);
    player->inputBuffer->mNumberBuffers = player->streamFormat.mChannelsPerFrame;

    //Pre malloc buffers for AudioBufferLists
    for(UInt32 i = 0; i < player->inputBuffer->mNumberBuffers; i++){
        player->inputBuffer->mBuffers[i].mNumberChannels = 1;
        player->inputBuffer->mBuffers[i].mDataByteSize = bufferSizeBytes;
        player->inputBuffer->mBuffers[i].mData = malloc(bufferSizeBytes);
    }

    //Create the ring buffer
    player->ringBuffer = new CARingBuffer();
    player->ringBuffer->Allocate(player->streamFormat.mChannelsPerFrame,
                             player->streamFormat.mBytesPerFrame,
                             bufferSizeFrames * 3);

    printf("Number of channels: %d\n", player->streamFormat.mChannelsPerFrame);
    printf("Number of buffers: %d\n", player->inputBuffer->mNumberBuffers);


    //Set render proc to supply samples
    AURenderCallbackStruct callbackStruct;
    callbackStruct.inputProc = InputRenderProc;
    callbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = player;

    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(player->inputUnit,
                                kAudioOutputUnitProperty_SetInputCallback,
                                kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                                0,
                                &callbackStruct,
                                sizeof(callbackStruct);
    assert(status == noErr);

    status = AudioUnitInitialize(player->inputUnit);
    assert(status == noErr);

    player->firstInputSampleTime = -1;
    player->inToOutSampleTimeOffset = -1;

    printf("Finished CreateInputUnit()\n");

}
```

So this is my render callback function where I am accessing the individual buffers. :

```
OSStatus GraphRenderProc(void * inRefCon,
                     AudioUnitRenderActionFlags * ioActionFlags,
                     const AudioTimeStamp * inTimeStamp,
                     UInt32 inBusNumber,
                     UInt32 inNumberFrames,
                     AudioBufferList * ioData)
{
    MyAUGraphPlayer * player = (MyAUGraphPlayer *) inRefCon;

    if(player->firstOutputSampleTime < 0.0) {
        player->firstOutputSampleTime = inTimeStamp->mSampleTime;
        if((player->firstInputSampleTime > -1.0) &&
           (player->inToOutSampleTimeOffset < 0.0)) {
            player->inToOutSampleTimeOffset = player->firstInputSampleTime - player->firstOutputSampleTime;
        }
    }

    //Copy samples out of ring buffer
    OSStatus outputProcErr = noErr;

    outputProcErr = player->ringBuffer->Fetch(ioData,
                                          inNumberFrames,
                                          inTimeStamp->mSampleTime + player->inToOutSampleTimeOffset);


    //BUT THIS IS NOT HOW IT IS SUPPOSED TO WORK
    Float32 * data = (Float32 *) ioData->mBuffers[0].mData;
    Float32 * data2 = (Float32 *) ioData->mBuffers[1].mData;



    for(int frame = 0; frame < inNumberFrames; frame++)
    {
        Float32 sample =  data[frame] + data2[frame];
        data[frame] = data2[frame] = sample;
    }


    return outputProcErr;
}
```

Comment: If you don't post at least an example of what you've done, you let people guess and judge upon your wording...

Comment: i added some example code. let me know if you need anything else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your code looks overly complicated for the task it seems to manage, I'll try to answer your question:

There's nothing wrong with your concept of *retrieving sample data* inside a callback. It would though be insufficient if dealing with multichannel audio devices. How many channels the device has and which is the channel layout, format etc. you query through `AudioStreamBasicDescription` for given device. This property serves for the initialization of the rest of your processing chain. You allocate audio buffers on initialization, or let the program do it for you (please read documentation).

In case you find more comfortable using extra buffers to copy to just for data crunching and DSP, you can manage it inside your callback like this (simplified code):

```
Float32 buf[streamFormat.mChanelsPerFrame][inNumberFrames];

for(int ch; ch < streamFormat.mChanelsPerFrame; ch++){
    Float32 data = (Float32 *)ioData->mBuffers[ch].mData;
    memcpy(buf[ch], data, inNumberFrames*sizeof(Float32));
}
```

Comment: Just to confirm, by " be insufficient if dealing with multichannel audio devices" do you mean that if i had an 8 channel input interface and i just want to output to stereo that would not be the recommended way?

Comment: Which stereo? If you want to write a good program you never know how many channels will an external device provide and which of them can have an input signal and which of those signals will go out. You may want to make a _stereo out_ from, let's say, _in #7_ and in _#12_, just to keep it simple. (-:

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't clear. I want to see if there was a recommended approach to create a DAW app like garageband or logic in regards to interfacing with external audio interfaces.

Comment: I'm afraid you are confusing recording tracks, audio channels and virtual tracks. As for _audio channels_ the above method is the only documented approach I know. As for managing _track-objects_, _track-to-channel_ mapping matrices, _per-track-plug-in-chain-hosting_, _cross-track-messaging API_, I cannot give an answer. Source code of "LogicPro" and "GarageBand" hasn't been published. If you plan to develop a commercial DAW, there are ways of learning it, but that is already _business_, not _SO_, IMHO. Perhaps there is source code of AULab.app published. I'm not sure.

Comment: Ahh yes I am confusing those 3 terms. Do you mind quickly explaining the 3 terms? Am I correct to assume that by "audio channels" you mean the inputs from an external hardware? If so, then (if i understand you correctly) accessing each of the buffers individually is the only way to access samples from each individual input from an external audio interface? I have no plans on developing a DAW because i know that would be just reinventing the wheel :). I like working with audio stuff and just want to learn more about it.

Comment: Yes, this is the 'legit' way of accessing individual channels. (1) audio channel is a property of signal or data stream format (2) recording track belongs to audio file concept (3) virtual track is a DAW control surface layout concept. There is quite a lot of excellent literature on this subject. Please, don't look for shortcuts - it'll pay off. Last but not least, in your neighborhood there are few *world leading* academic institutions for computer music and sound research and education (CCRMA, CNMAT…). If you really want to learn, you're lucky.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. You have clarified a lot for me. Yes CCRMA and CNMAT are great resources. I wish I can take couple classes from them, but with a full time schedule and what not it gets tough. If I may ask do you have any recommendation for literature on this topic?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113864/discussion-between-user3078414-and-moses-j-lee).